# Facebook Access to users photos using my app token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo, user-permissions

Having problems gaining access to a users photo's from my Facebook app.

I request the apps token at runtime using: (replacing the values in [] brackets with actual values.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[clientid]&client_secret=[clientsecret]&grant_type=client_credentials

I then try to access a users photo using that access token, ie:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT pid, src_big, src_small FROM photo WHERE pid IN('4313357036026642248','4313357036026642249','4313357036026642250','4313357036026642251','4313357036026642252','4313357036026642253','4313357036026642254')

The user has authenticated themselves with my app and accepted the USER_PHOTO permissions.

However I get 0 results back. I do get results back when I use that users access token rather than the app token.

I have proven this issue on the graph explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1004281695

Anyone got any ideas why an app that has been granted access to a user photos cannot get those photos using the app access token ?

Thanks in advance, Rhys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because with very few exceptions, you can only access a user's data using a valid access token for that user (or one of their friends, depending on the privacy of the object in question).

In this case, use the user's access token, the app access token is for acting on behalf of the app and shouldn't really be used for user-specific calls, as it won't be able to see non-public information except with very limited circumstances

Comment: Thanks for the response. However in this case user a would upload photos to the app (or rather link photos to the app). user b would then need to view user a's upload. User a and user b are not friends but they have both accepted User_photos permissions on the app so why can't the app see both user a and user b's photos ?

Comment: If the photos are from a facebook album of User A that user B can't see, why would user B be able to see it via the app? If the photos exist in your own app's context, you'd need to store the details in your own database

Comment: Ok maybe I have missed the point - I assumed that by giving photo access to an app would mean that app could get that users photos. therefore someone else using the app could see those photos because the app has access to them. I do store the details of the photos in my db but I fetch the actual image from facebook.

Comment: I think in your case you'd need to store the direct photo URLs in order to show them to another user,e but if that other user wouldn't ordinarily be able to access the photos on facebook itself it may be against policy to do this

Comment: Ok Igy thanks for your answers, Previous versions of the app did store the url's to the photo's. However FB change these every so often. Bottom line is that user b can only see user a's pictures if they are in a public album. Thanks again. Rhys

Comment: Just had a better idea ! I will create an album for the App. users can then upload pictures to that album and the App will therefore have access to them :)